# SwiftUI: implementing ZStack inside of navigationBarItems shows navigationBarItems error

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, zstack, navigationbaritems, swiftui-zstack

I'm trying to implement a `ZStack` inside of `navigationBarItems` to load a custom alert. Here is my implementation:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List(self.itemsStore.names){ item in
                Text("hello")
            }
        }
        
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            ZStack {
                ItemsAlert(isShown: $isPresented, text: $text)
            }
            
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }))
    }
```

On this line I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this warning? or if is a work around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put SwiftUI view in closure - it has not sense, view should be in the view hierarchy, button can activate states to manipulate with views, like

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ItemsAlert(isShown: $isPresented, text: $text)
        
        VStack{
           List(self.itemsStore.names){ item in
               Text("hello")
           }
        }
    }

    
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
       self.isPresented = true    // << activate state            
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }))
}
```